# DNN website issues

Tags: iis-7, dotnetnuke, asp.net-4.5

We followed every steps given in installation guide in dot net nuke site for `DotNetNuke_Community_07.00.02`. We have database server on virtual machine and we use **SQL server authentication**.

1) When we click edit page in home page it redirect to home page and nothing happens. 
2) When we check chrome console it shows

> POST
>   http://dnndev.me/DesktopModules/internalservices/API/controlbar/ToggleUserMode
>   401       (Unauthorized)

Please anybody can tell me what I am going wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Chris, we had a lot more installed, we removed it and set it exactly as you have given above but no luck. Tried reinstalling aspnet_regiis -i as well but still no luck.

It is certain that the authentication is the issue. Please note that the machine is a Windows 7 machine and is on a domain.

We have also double checked that the app pool uses the app pool identity and not LOCALSERVICE etc. We use a SQL Server on another machine and it uses the sa account at this time which is absolutely powerful.

Please see the following extract from Failed Trace. I have also dumped the trace preceding the Warning.

```
ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification 128 
HttpStatus 401 
HttpReason Unauthorized 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo  
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0) 
35.  AspNetPipelineEnter Data1="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Services.ServicesModule" 10:14:06.910 
36.  AspNetPipelineLeave Data1="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Services.ServicesModule" 10:14:06.910 
37.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="Services", Notification="BEGIN_REQUEST", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910 
38.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="IsapiFilterModule", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotification="false" 10:14:06.910 
39.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="IsapiFilterModule",Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST",fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910
40.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="BasicAuthenticationModule",Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST",fIsPostNotification="false" 10:14:06.910 i AUTH_START AuthTypeSupported="Basic" 10:14:06.910
 1. i AUTH_END  10:14:06.910 
 2.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="BasicAuthenticationModule", 
Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910
 3.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="WindowsAuthenticationModule", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotification="false" 10:14:06.910
 4. i AUTH_START AuthTypeSupported="NT" 10:14:06.910
 5. i AUTH_END  10:14:06.910
 6.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="WindowsAuthenticationModule", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910
 7.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="AnonymousAuthenticationModule", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotification="false" 10:14:06.910
 8. i AUTH_START AuthTypeSupported="Anonymous" 10:14:06.910
 9. i AUTH_REQUEST_AUTH_TYPE RequestAuthType="Anonymous" 10:14:06.910
 10. i AUTH_SUCCEEDED AuthType="NT", NTLMUsed="false", RemoteUserName="", AuthUserName="", TokenImpersonationLevel="ImpersonationImpersonate" 10:14:06.910
11. i USER_SET AuthType="", UserName="", SupportsIsInRole="true" 10:14:06.910
12. i AUTH_END  10:14:06.910
13.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="AnonymousAuthenticationModule", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910 
14.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="IsapiFilterModule", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotification="true" 10:14:06.910 
15. i FILTER_AUTH_COMPLETE_START  10:14:06.910 
16. i FILTER_AUTH_COMPLETE_END  10:14:06.910 
17.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="IsapiFilterModule", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotificationEvent="true", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910 
18. i FILE_CACHE_ACCESS_START FileName="D:\DNN\DesktopModules\internalservices\API\controlbar\ToggleUserMode", UserName="IUSR", DomainName="NT AUTHORITY" 10:14:06.910
19. i FILE_CACHE_ACCESS_END Successful="false", FileFromCache="false", FileAddedToCache="false", FileDirmoned="true", LastModCheckErrorIgnored="true", ErrorCode="The system cannot find the path specified.
(0x80070003)", LastModifiedTime="" 10:14:06.910 
20.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="HttpCacheModule", Notification="RESOLVE_REQUEST_CACHE", fIsPostNotification="false" 10:14:06.910 
21. i OUTPUT_CACHE_LOOKUP_START  10:14:06.910
22. i OUTPUT_CACHE_LOOKUP_END Result="NOT_FOUND" 10:14:06.910
23.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="HttpCacheModule", Notification="RESOLVE_REQUEST_CACHE", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910
24.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="UrlRoutingModule-4.0", Notification="RESOLVE_REQUEST_CACHE", fIsPostNotification="true" 10:14:06.910
25.  AspNetPipelineEnter Data1="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" 10:14:06.910
26.  AspNetPipelineLeave Data1="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" 10:14:06.910
27.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="UrlRoutingModule-4.0", Notification="RESOLVE_REQUEST_CACHE", fIsPostNotificationEvent="true", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910
28.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="StaticCompressionModule", Notification="MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotification="false" 10:14:06.910
29.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="StaticCompressionModule", Notification="MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910
30.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotification="false" 10:14:06.910
31.  AspNetMapHandlerEnter  10:14:06.910
32. i HANDLER_CHANGED OldHandlerName="StaticFile", NewHandlerName="System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler", NewHandlerModules="ManagedPipelineHandler", NewHandlerScriptProcessor="", NewHandlerType="System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler, System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 10:14:06.910
33.  AspNetMapHandlerLeave  10:14:06.910
34.  NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 10:14:06.910 
35.  NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotification="false" 10:14:06.910 
36.  AspNetPipelineEnter Data1="System.Web.ImplicitAsyncPreloadModule" 10:14:06.910 
37.  AspNetPipelineLeave Data1="System.Web.ImplicitAsyncPreloadModule" 10:14:06.910
38. i AspNetHttpHandlerEnter  10:14:06.910
39. i AspNetHttpHandlerLeave  10:14:07.363
40. r MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
Warning ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="401", HttpReason="Unauthorized", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.
(0x0)", ConfigExceptionInfo="" 10:14:07.363
41. i OUTPUT_CACHE_DISABLED  10:14:07.363
42.  NOTIFY_MODULE_COMPLETION ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", CompletionBytes="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.
(0x0)"
```

Answer (score 6):

I just had a similar issue tonight with `DNN 7.2.1` but instead of a `401` I was getting a `404` on `/DesktopModules/internalservices/API/controlbar/ToggleUserMode.`

I remembered that I had just been actively developing a new project with the latest version of `NewtonSoft.Json.dll`. After I restored that file to the original that came with `DNN 7.2.1` I was up and going again.

Comment: i had the same problem :-(

Comment: This was my issue. I was developing a custom module where I used NuGet to install the newest version of Newtonsoft.Json which overrides the dependent version in DNN when compiled and deployed. Once I grabbed the original version from the DNN installer package (and changed the reference in my custom module) it was all better!

Comment: Had a customer with the same problem, thanks for the fix

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error being reported a bit lately, though I am not sure what causes this. It would appear to me that perhaps your ASP.NET settings are off for IIS. Could you try to aspnet_regiis -i from the commandline and see if that addresses the problem? You might also need to check the Windows configuration for IIS making sure all the proper options are enabled. I've taken a screenshot of my IIS installation options in Windows to see if that helps you.

[image: IIS Settings]

Answer (score 0):

This is s a fairly common issue in 7.x and unfortunately there are a few possible causes and some of them are still not fully understood. Please go through this thread and try the suggested fixes.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/190/threadid/469106/scope/posts/threadpage/2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could update your web.config and modify the modules tag with the following property.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, tried all solutions from [here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Problems-with-edit-mode.aspx).

Changing from `Controlbar` to `Ribbonbar` **worked** for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not resolved even after keeping the

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

tag in **web.config**, then check whether the **Newtonsoft.Json.dll** is present in your Dotnetnuke's **bin** folder.

Try with this, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Go to host-settings,
changing from Controlbar to Ribbonbar worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Benesh Thank you, i am with you. For now i have insufficient reputation and not be able to comment on any post. :)